# ¿Como contar/sumar los valores de las columnas de una tabla pivot? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Eh estado investigado un poco y no he podido encontrar algo que me ayude a saber como sumar o contar los valores de las columnas de mi tabla pivot para agregar otra columna con el total y dependiendo del total agregar otra columna con estatus el cual determinará si esta completo o pendiente de acuerdo si tiene las 15 columnas completas(Con 1), este es el query que tengo:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT workDayId,calif,clave FROM cteMechanicals_Two) P
                    PIVOT  
                    (  
                    COUNT (calif)  
                    FOR clave IN ([MX-SI14-06],[MX-SI14-14],[MX-AG16-529],[MX-PB10-008],[MX-AG14-546],[MX-WH10-001],
                    [MX-AG14-079],[MX-SI14-08],[MX-PS14-007],[MX-PS10-068],[MX-PB14-04],[MX-SI14-17],[MX-PS10-154],[MX-AG14-597],
                    [MX-SI10-014])) AS pvt
```

Y este es el resultado que tengo hasta ahora | El que espero:
[image: Resultado]

¿Como puedo contar/sumar los valores de las columnas y obtener un resultado igual al anterior? Espero y me puedan ayudar, realmente no se si esto es posible, apenas estoy aprendiendo a saber como funcionan y como realizar tablas pivot. Gracias por su apoyo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siempre recomiendo dejar de usar `PIVOT` y en su lugar usar agregados condicionales. Esto da una flexibilidad mayor y, aunque requiera más texto, generarlo es solo cuestión de copiar, pegar y modificar cosas básicas.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT workDayId,
        COUNT( CASE WHEN clave = 'MX-SI14-06 ' THEN calif END) AS [MX-SI14-06],
        COUNT( CASE WHEN clave = 'MX-SI14-14 ' THEN calif END) AS [MX-SI14-14],
        COUNT( CASE WHEN clave = 'MX-AG16-529' THEN calif END) AS [MX-AG16-529],
        COUNT( CASE WHEN clave = 'MX-PB10-008' THEN calif END) AS [MX-PB10-008],
        COUNT( CASE WHEN clave = 'MX-AG14-546' THEN calif END) AS [MX-AG14-546],
        COUNT( CASE WHEN clave = 'MX-WH10-001' THEN calif END) AS [MX-WH10-001],
        COUNT( CASE WHEN clave = 'MX-AG14-079' THEN calif END) AS [MX-AG14-079],
        COUNT( CASE WHEN clave = 'MX-SI14-08 ' THEN calif END) AS [MX-SI14-08],
        COUNT( CASE WHEN clave = 'MX-PS14-007' THEN calif END) AS [MX-PS14-007],
        COUNT( CASE WHEN clave = 'MX-PS10-068' THEN calif END) AS [MX-PS10-068],
        COUNT( CASE WHEN clave = 'MX-PB14-04 ' THEN calif END) AS [MX-PB14-04],
        COUNT( CASE WHEN clave = 'MX-SI14-17 ' THEN calif END) AS [MX-SI14-17],
        COUNT( CASE WHEN clave = 'MX-PS10-154' THEN calif END) AS [MX-PS10-154],
        COUNT( CASE WHEN clave = 'MX-AG14-597' THEN calif END) AS [MX-AG14-597],
        COUNT( CASE WHEN clave = 'MX-SI10-014' THEN calif END) AS [MX-SI10-014]`
        COUNT( clave) AS Total,
        CASE WHEN COUNT( clave) = 15 THEN 'Completo' ELSE 'Pendiente' END AS Estatus
FROM cteMechanicals_Two
GROUP BY workDayId;
```

Claro está, que para hacer lo que pides, solo tendrías que hacer la suma. Como vas a usar esa suma 2 veces, se puede factorizar en un `APPLY`.

```
SELECT workDayId,
        [MX-SI14-06], [MX-SI14-14], [MX-AG16-529], [MX-PB10-008], [MX-AG14-546],
        [MX-WH10-001], [MX-AG14-079], [MX-SI14-08], [MX-PS14-007], [MX-PS10-068],
        [MX-PB14-04], [MX-SI14-17], [MX-PS10-154], [MX-AG14-597], [MX-SI10-014],
        t.total,
        CASE WHEN total = 15 THEN 'Completo' ELSE 'Pendiente' END AS Estatus
FROM (SELECT workDayId,calif,clave FROM cteMechanicals_Two) P
PIVOT  (COUNT (calif) 
        FOR clave IN ([MX-SI14-06], [MX-SI14-14], [MX-AG16-529], [MX-PB10-008], [MX-AG14-546],
                    [MX-WH10-001], [MX-AG14-079], [MX-SI14-08], [MX-PS14-007], [MX-PS10-068],
                    [MX-PB14-04], [MX-SI14-17], [MX-PS10-154], [MX-AG14-597], [MX-SI10-014] )) AS pvt
CROSS APPLY( SELECT [MX-SI14-06] + [MX-SI14-14] + [MX-AG16-529] + [MX-PB10-008] + [MX-AG14-546] +
                    [MX-WH10-001] + [MX-AG14-079] + [MX-SI14-08] + [MX-PS14-007] + [MX-PS10-068] +
                    [MX-PB14-04] + [MX-SI14-17] + [MX-PS10-154] + [MX-AG14-597] + [MX-SI10-014]  AS total) t;
```

Comment: Gracias! esto era lo que estaba buscando, solo una pregunta... ¿El `Cross Apply` solo es para factorizar el primer query que agregaste? o sirve para realizar la suma de los valores de las columnas? Tendre que investigar sobre esto más a fondo para poder entenderlo correctamente.

Comment: El cross apply lo uso para no tener que repetir la expresión de la suma y solo hacer referencia mediante el nombre de la columna.

Comment: Amigo, una pregunta... ¿Como puedo aplicar aquí un `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Al final de la consulta, antes del punto y coma. Recuerda que en el `ORDER BY` puedes hacer referencia a los alias de las columnas.

Comment: Tengo otro problema, tomando como ejemplo la imagen que agregue en mi pregunta si una persona tiene `N/A` en la columna calif ¿Como puedo hacer para que en mi pivot me aparezca `N/A`? ya que por el `COUNT(calif)` me regresa 1